# Will there be flowers blooming in the last week of March at the St. Louis Botanical Garden?

Tags: usa

I'm traveling there from 03/26-28 for business and would like to see a few things, one of which is the St. Louis Botanical Garden.

Answer (score 4):

They have an official ["What's in Bloom?"](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/our-garden/whats-in-bloom.aspx) page!

For [March](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/our-garden/whats-in-bloom/march.aspx), you may be lucky enough to see cherry blossom, as well as crocuses, vines, daisies and more.

Of course, like with any plant life, if it's unseasonably warm or cold the bloom may happen slightly earlier or later, so check February and April as well for an idea of what might also be occuring.

Comment: This is a great resource. It has a lot of information and education about flowers and many things in nature. They're well-known for involvement in conservation, sustainability and other ways to keep the environment alive and thriving!